# How do I insert an image name into a database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, image

I succeed to upload and image and resize it. Now I want to insert my image's name into the database.

I'm using SQL Server. The table is named `images` and has two columns, an integer `imageid` and `imagename` as `string(invarchar(max))`. I need the file name saved in the imagename column and `imageid` must be an identity.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnupload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupload.Click
        Response.Write("Done")
        If (IsPostBack) Then
            HandleUploadedFile()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub HandleUploadedFile()
        ' get the root of the web site 
        Dim root As String = Server.MapPath("~/")

        ' clean up the path 
        If Not root.EndsWith("\") Then
            root += "\"
        End If

        ' make a folder to store the images in 
        Dim fileDirectory As String = root & "Images/"

        ' create the folder if it does not exist 
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(fileDirectory) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDirectory)
        End If

        ' make a link to the new file 
        Dim link As String = "<a href='Images/{0}' target='_blank'>{1}</a>{2}{3}"

        ' loop through the file in the request 
        For i As Integer = 0 To Request.Files.Count - 1

            ' get the file instance 
            Dim fi As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files.[Get](i)

            ' create a byte array to store the file bytes 
            Dim fileBytes As Byte() = New Byte(fi.ContentLength - 1) {}

            ' fill the byte array 
            Using stream As System.IO.Stream = fi.InputStream
                stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fi.ContentLength)
            End Using

            ' create a random file name 
            Dim fileName As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

            ' write the original file to the file system 
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileDirectory + fileName & ".jpg", fileBytes)
            litText.Text += String.Format(link, fileName & ".jpg", fileName & " Original", "<br/>", "")

            ' write the resized file to the file system 
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileDirectory + fileName & "_small.jpg", ResizeImageFile(fileBytes, 100))
            litText.Text += String.Format(link, fileName & "_small.jpg", fileName & " Small", "<br/>", "<br/>")

            ' cleanup 
            litText.Visible = True
            fileBytes = Nothing
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Shared Function ResizeImageFile(ByVal imageFile As Byte(), ByVal targetSize As Integer) As Byte()
        Using oldImage As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(imageFile))
            Dim newSize As Size = CalculateDimensions(oldImage.Size, targetSize)
            Using newImage As New Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
                Using canvas As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
                    canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
                    canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                    canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                    canvas.DrawImage(oldImage, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), newSize))
                    Dim m As New MemoryStream()
                    newImage.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                    Return m.GetBuffer()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
    Private Shared Function CalculateDimensions(ByVal oldSize As Size, ByVal targetSize As Integer) As Size
        Dim newSize As New Size()
        If oldSize.Height > oldSize.Width Then
            newSize.Width = CInt((oldSize.Width * (CSng(targetSize) / CSng(oldSize.Height))))
            newSize.Height = targetSize
        Else
            newSize.Width = targetSize
            newSize.Height = CInt((oldSize.Height * (CSng(targetSize) / CSng(oldSize.Width))))
        End If
        Return newSize
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: That may be the code, but what's your question?

Comment: i want to know how to add the image name in the database

Comment: What kind of database? What server? What table schema? What OS? What execution context? What runtime environment? A clarification that just adds "I want to know how to do the thing I didn't explain previously" is not actually a clarification :)

Comment: its sql server with table name images with two column first is imageid with value int and the other is imagename with value string(invarchar(max)) and i want the file name is save in the imagename column and i make the id identity

Comment: I incorporated your comment into the post - Jeremy posted some example below. Generally, it's best if you provide useful info and edit your posts by yourself when people ask for clarifications - there might not always be someone around to help :) Hope this was helpful, maybe we'll see you around.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know your Connection String. since the code is referencing the SQLClient I'll assume you are using SQL Server so you should look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#1).  Next you'll want to use the ExecuteNonQuery method of the SQLCommand object. I've pasted a sample below. You can read more about the SQLCommand object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx). And this [site](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_insert.asp) covers Insert statements.

```
Public Sub SaveNameInDatabase(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO Files_Table (FileName) Values (\"{0}\")",fileName)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```